# Java - Selecting a random shape from pre-designed shapes

Tags: java, random, shapes

I'm having a problem randomly selecting a shape from pre-designed shapes in Java.  Previously, I was able to create a random shape but I'm getting no-where with this.

My code is below.  I need "DIE07" to randomly be DIE01-DIE06.  All help is very much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;


public class FigurePanel extends JPanel {
     public static final int DIE01 = 1;
     public static final int DIE02 = 2;
     public static final int DIE03 = 3;
     public static final int DIE04 = 4;
     public static final int DIE05 = 5;
     public static final int DIE06 = 6;
     public static final int DIE07 = 7;
     Random rand = new Random();

     private int type = 1;
     private boolean filled = false;

     public FigurePanel() {
     }

     public FigurePanel(int type) {
     this.type = type;
     }

     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);

     int width = getWidth();
     int height = getHeight();

     switch (type) {
     case DIE01:
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
        (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
     g.fillOval((int)(0.44 * width), (int)(0.46 * height),
            (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
     break;
   case DIE02:
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      break;
  case DIE03:
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.45 * width), (int)(0.46 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      break;
  case DIE04:
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height)); 
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      break;
  case DIE05:
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.45 * width), (int)(0.46 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));   
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      break;
  case DIE06:
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawRoundRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.25 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.5 * height), 20, 20);
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height)); 
      g.fillOval((int)(0.27 * width), (int)(0.46 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height)); 
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.46 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height)); 
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.58 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      g.fillOval((int)(0.63 * width), (int)(0.34 * height),
              (int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.075 * height));
      break;
  case DIE07:

      break;
}

   }
    public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
    repaint();
   }

    public int getType() {
    return type;
   }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
    repaint();
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
    return filled;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(80, 80);
    }
    }
```

and this...

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TestFigurePanel extends JFrame {
    public TestFigurePanel() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 7, 1, 1));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE01));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE02));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE03));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE04));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE05));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE06));
    add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.DIE07));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestFigurePanel frame = new TestFigurePanel();
    frame.setSize(1100, 300);
    frame.setTitle("TestFigurePanel");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: a short note on design: you should make the 6 pre-designed shapes subclasses of a common superclass and use a factory-method (with the shape-id as parameter) to instantiate each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `Random` member instance to instantiate your `type` randomly if the passed argument is `DIE07`. If not, you assign it to your `type` directly.

```
public FigurePanel(int type) {
  if (type == DIE07) {
    this.type = DIE01 + rand.nextInt(DIE06);
  } else {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

`Random#nextInt(int n)` returns a random `int` value between `0` (inclusive) and the specified value `n` (exclusive). So, `DIE01 + rand.nextInt(DIE06)` will return an `int` value between `DIE01` to `DIE06` (both inclusive).

Comment: `this.type = DIE01 + rand.nextInt(DIE07);` would return a value from 1 to 7 and not 1 to 6. This should be `this.type = DIE01 + rand.nextInt(DIE06);`

Comment: Thanks, Neo.  Your edit makes sense and is corrected on my end.  You both rock!

Comment: Thanks, Neo for the catch. @KenWright Please note there was a small typo in my answer as pointed by Neo. Please make sure you update your code or you'll randomly set `type` to `DIE07` as well.